# GDB reading symbols with "symbol-file" command on a core file

Tags: c++, gdb, core-file

I am trying to analyze segfault on a core file on linux.  I am not sure if the following behavior is correct, thus i deliberately caused a  segfault using

```
#include <signal.h>
int main() {
raise(SIGSEGV); 
}
```

the binary is build with debug info i.e.

```
file mainTestFile 
mainTestFile: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
```

notice how it does say "with debug_info, not stripped"  at the end

when i execute the binary i get a core file generated which is called  core-mainTestFile.20474
(In order to generate the core file i hat to set my ulimit to unlimited i.e. 
ulimit -c unlimited
)

if i run only the binary under GDB and do backtrace "bt" then i get the segfault and i get all names of the functions involved 
printed nicely i.e. notice how the gdb says when starting "reading symbols from ./mainTestFile...done."

```
gdb ./mainTestFile
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3) 8.1.0.20180409-git

....

reading symbols from ./mainTestFile...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /src/exe/mainTestFile 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".


Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x0000000000402dad in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffda38) at /src/exe/main.cpp:53
(gdb)
```

however if i try to anaylise only the core file with gdb like that

```
gdb -c core-mainTestFile.20474
```

then i get only question marks

the when i execute "bt" then i do not see the names of the methods, instead i get question marks

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f34d8842e97 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

they only workaround i found is to supply the binary directly at the command line then it all gets printed nicely. 
 even if i try to tell GDB to use the symbols file  and point that to the binary file which does have the symbols
i.e.

```
symbol-file /src/exe/mainTestFile
```

then GDB says

```
Reading symbols from /src/exe/mainTestFile...done
```

and when i execute  bt i see the question marks again? Why is that. Is GDB not able to get the symbols out of the binary?

it only works if supply the binary directly on the command like like:

```
gdb /src/exe/mainTestFile -c core-mainTestFile.20474
```

my question is should the GDB be able to read symbols of the binary when directly supplying him  the binary over the "symbol-file" command or not. Why is this working when supping him directly the binary over the command line, what is the difference?

Answer (score 4):

> should the GDB be able to read symbols of the binary when directly supplying him the binary over the "symbol-file" command or not.

In theory, using `symbol-file` and `core-file` commands in *either* order in GDB should be equivalent.

But there is a bug: `symbol-file` followed by `core-file` works, and the opposite order doesn't.

Since generally the end-user can always rearrange his commands into the order that works, this has never propagated to the top of any GDB developer's queue of things to fix.

Related [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25632037/50617) (but not an exact duplicate).